SQL Foreign Key issue preventing setup:upgrade from completing
I am running into an issue when trying to run setup:upgrade, to where it fails with saying;

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'REVIEW_STATUS_ID_REVIEW_STATUS_STATUS_ID'; check that column/key exists, query was: ALTER TABLE review DROP FOREIGN KEY REVIEW_STATUS_ID_REVIEW_STATUS_STATUS_ID

I don't have any reviews, so my review table is empty (and never been touched), and as far as I know, default with what it has inside it;

I am not even exactly sure what could've changed in the system to even have it looking/trying to mess with that section (in trying to drop its foreign key all of a sudden).
Any ideas what could be the issue here?
Or is there a simple way to fix it -- by creating a makeshift foreign key just to appease its request perhaps?
UPDATE:
I have also since, tried to manually remove said foreign key by going into the database and doing;

ALTER TABLE review DROP FOREIGN KEY REVIEW_STATUS_ID_REVIEW_STATUS_STATUS_ID;

However it comes with the same information of;

#1091 - Can't DROP 'REVIEW_STATUS_ID_REVIEW_STATUS_STATUS_ID'; check that column/key exists


Execute this query in your Database as I can see that foreign key index has been deleted or while migrating it has been missed.
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
CREATE TABLE `review` (
  `review_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Review ID',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Review create date',
  `entity_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `entity_pk_value` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product ID',
  `status_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Status code'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COMMENT='Review base information';

ALTER TABLE `review`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`),
  ADD KEY `REVIEW_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  ADD KEY `REVIEW_STATUS_ID` (`status_id`),
  ADD KEY `REVIEW_ENTITY_PK_VALUE` (`entity_pk_value`);
ALTER TABLE `review`
  MODIFY `review_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Review ID', AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `review`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `REVIEW_ENTITY_ID_REVIEW_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `review_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `REVIEW_STATUS_ID_REVIEW_STATUS_STATUS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `review_status` (`status_id`);
COMMIT;

